# Stacked columns with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have three stacked columns within the window screen. The first one to set height depending on the set HTML content, the second as well but flexibel since js will append a lot of markup. The last column should have a set height of like 300px or fill the rest of the screen.

Any suggestions of how to make this work with flexbox that's kind of responsive?

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-child red">Flexibel height(HTML already in place)</div>
  <div class="flex-child orange"> content will be displayed from js so flexibel height </div>
  <div class="flex-child yellow">I would like to have a set height on this one</div>
</div>

.flexbox {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZYgzx

Comment: Can you use CSS-Grid browser-support-wise? This could be done in grid pretty straightforward.

Comment: Also I'm not sure I get the requirements fully, but is that what you need: https://codepen.io/niorad/pen/ypraxd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you code does now, is to make each item take an equal space of the available space in the parent.

> The last column should have a set height of like 300px or fill the
>   rest of the screen.

If you use `flex: 1` on the last item only, it will take the available space left.

```css
html,body {margin: 0; }

.flexbox {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.red {background: red;}
.orange {background: orange;}
.yellow {background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-child red">Flexibel height,<br>with 2 lines</div>
  <div class="flex-child orange"> A lot of content will be displayed with js,<br>here with more than<br>2 lines</div>
  <div class="flex-child yellow">I would like to have a set height</div>
</div>
```

If you use `flex-basis: 300px` on the last item only, it will be either:

- 300px high, if there is enough space and content is not higher
- fill space, if not enough space and content is not higher
- if content is higher than 300px or the filled available space, it will not shrink past content height

```css
html,body {margin: 0; }

.flexbox {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child:last-child {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

.red {background: red;}
.orange {background: orange;}
.yellow {background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-child red">Flexibel height,<br>with 2 lines</div>
  <div class="flex-child orange"> A lot of content will be displayed with js,<br>here with more than<br>2 lines</div>
  <div class="flex-child yellow">I would like to have a set height</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `flex: 0 0 300px` instead of `height: 300px` to your fixed height div. This mean :

- 0 = don't grow
- 0 = don't shrink
- 300px = start at 300px

[Your pen](https://codepen.io/erevan/pen/jYRMeJ)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.flexbox {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: columns wrap;
}

.red{
  width:auto;
  background: red;
}
.orange{
  max-height:300px;
  background: orange;
}
.yellow{
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-child red">Flexibel height(HTML already in place)</div>
  <div class="flex-child orange"> content will be displayed from js so flexibel height </div>
  <div class="flex-child yellow">I would like to have a set height on this one</div>
</div>
```

You have to set the columns direction (I used `wrap` but you can use `nowrap` also, as you need). For the first one `auto`, the second one `max-width` or `width` (if you want to set it) and for the last one a `100%`.